# Change y axis title has no effect on ggplotly hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have a ggplot object created in this way:

```
p<-ggplot(melt.cluster.data)+
  geom_histogram( aes(x = value,y=(..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..],fill=variable)) +
  facet_grid(CLUSTER_CLARA~variable,scales="free")+
  aes(fill = variable)+
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=8,face="bold"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(size=12, face="bold"),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="#CCCCFF"))+
  labs(y="Numero Clienti",xlab="")+
  theme(legend.position =  "none")
```

I want to have an interactive plot so i'll call `ggplotly`

```
ggplotly(p)%>%config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Although I rename with `labs` the y axis title, I still got on the hover `(..count..)/tapply(..count..,..PANEL..,sum)[..PANEL..]` which is pretty ugly

[image]

How can I fix this?